# Ruby and Google Maps API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3

I'm requesting directions with the following url:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.656877,-79.32085&destination=Montreal&sensor=false
```

Then, Google sends back a huge JSON and I want to access the steps in a nicer way than this:

```
response = open("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=#{lat1},#{lng1}&destination=#{lat2},#{lng2}&sensor=false").read
response = JSON.parse(response)

response["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"][0]["end_location"]
```

Is there a more beautiful way to access the end_location without having to use all these array notation? I thought of using OpenStruct, but it would not be ideal either.

Comment: why don't you just write your own class, where you put the request stuff and some nice parsing methods in it? like ``def end_location \nresponse["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"][0]["end_location"]\n end``

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But because the scope of the project is changing quite a lot, I may end up fetching start_location or distance or something else. So, I need a more flexible syntax to do the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `[0]` with `first`, which is more characters but simpler concept and slightly faster.

```
response["routes"].first["legs"].first["steps"].first["end_location"]
```

Or, you can also do this:

```
["routes", 0, "legs", 0, "steps", 0, "end_location"].inject(response, &:fetch)
```